# ASP.NET Core Web Api "404 Page Not Found "

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi

i have a published project by using .Net Core Web Api. At local server porject works but after publish to live site, i get "404 Page Not Found".

My Controller Code is

```
namespace IMDBApi.Controllers
{
[Route("api/actors")]
public class ActorController : Controller
{
    private IActorInterface repository;

    public ActorController(IActorInterface repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetActor/{id}")]
    public string GetActor(string id)
    {
        string output = "";
        List<ActorModel> list = repository.GetActor(id);

        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            ErrorModel errorModel = new ErrorModel();
            errorModel.ErrorMessage = ConstVariables.NoDataFoundErrorMessage;
            output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorModel);
        }
        else
        {
            output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
}
```

Error is like this;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWQKi.png)

Comment: Try to remove    [HttpGet]

Comment: Did you host on IIS? If so,have you set the default document for the website?Refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831665(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Hi, @Sergey, i will try your suggestion.

Comment: Hi, @Rena, i host it on FTP Server. my dlls is in File Manager